# error in installing cudaSW++

Tags: cuda, bioinformatics

I'm trying to install cudaSW++, but I get this error message..please help me..

> mkdir -p objs nvcc -O3 -arch sm_13 --ptxas-options=-v -use_fast_math
>   -Xcompiler -funroll-loops -Xcompiler -msse2  -DMAX_SEQ_LENGTH_THRESHOLD=3072 -I. -I ~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK//C/common/inc -c GenericFunction.cu -o
>   objs/GenericFunction.cu.o GenericFunction.cu:14:19: error: cutil.h: No
>   such file or directory make: *** [objs/GenericFunction.cu.o] Error 1

Comment: While error message is welcome it would be nice to know how did you get there.

Comment: Are you using CUDA 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cutil.h` is part of older CUDA packages (CUDA 4.2 and prior).  It looks like the version of cudaSW++ you have is trying to use software elements from that older toolkit/package.

Probably the easiest approach is to download the CUDA 4.2 "SDK" from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-42-archive) and build the SDK using whatever toolchain you are currently using (e.g. CUDA 5 or CUDA 5.5) and you should have what you need.  Make sure your include and library paths in your cudaSW++ make files correctly point to the corresponding locations where your cuda 4.2 SDK is installed/built.

Answer (score 0):

You are building the old version. This may be on purpose, but could also be misunderstanding. In case it was not specifically your goal to build the old version, recent version of cudaSW that builds with CUDA 9.1 no problem seems available [here](https://github.com/coolmaksat/cudasw).